# Windows 7 Black Screen of Death issue

Tags: windows-7, boot, black-screen-of-death

I'm also facing a problem for last 4 days.  I use a Lenovo Thinkpad T410 with Windows 7 Professional OS. What I did was I pressed the power button to turn the computer off when it was on, as I was in a hurry.

Later on, when I tried to start the computer , it asked to the startup repair. When I started the repair, it ran for about 2-3 hours , then after reboot it was a black screen with just the cursor on.

I tried to do many troubleshooting but all gone in vein.

I even tried to check the registry value of Shell  under( `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/Current Version/Win logon`)  after accessing the registry from recovery option but after restarting the computer again the value changed to another value. I even tried to delete the existing Shell Key and created another key but nothing worked.

I don't have any restore point created and no recovery image saved on my Hard Disk.

I did even ran Memory Diagnostic tool, it ran the diagnostic but didn't find any problem.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried booting into [Safe Mode](http://supportforlenovo.iyogi.com/thinkpad-t410s/safemode-boot-10.html) and then `Use last-known good configuration`

Comment: Odd, I just answered a similar question and I fixed this for my father in law this weekend. Simply start the PC in safe mode, then do a system restore.

Comment: Dave, I have tried all the mentioned steps but no luck. Even if I try to boot the computer in Safe Mode/ Safe Mode with Networking, it just give me a black screen with big cursor. I even tried to use LKGC but in vein.